# How do I map one entity to many entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have 4 entities. They look something like this:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Client :
    Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier :
    Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
    public IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note :
    Entity
{
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; } // This points to the Id field of a Client or Supplier
    public virtual Entity Entity { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; } // "Client", "Supplier", etc.
}
```

Now, what I want is for this to create 3 tables, Client, Supplier, and Note. The note table needs to point to the client and supplier note on the EntityId field. What is actually happening, is that EF is adding Client_ID and Supplier_ID fields to the Note table, with foreign keys to each respective table. The effect of this is basically that notes can only be created if both client and supplier are included.

What do I need to do to make this behave the way I need?

Comment: isn't automapper what you are looking for ?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how automapper would solve this problem?

Comment: What about foreign key constraints? You would need a foreign key column in the note  table for each "parent" entity

Comment: What happens with just foreign keys is that it requires the Client and Supplier to be present in the note, therefore, it does not work.

Comment: This is the almost weekly incarnation of the *polymorphic associations* question.

Comment: If you use VS2015, look here: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/ - then you can model the database like you want and use the reverse engineer to generate the code first classes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.Client)
                .WithMany(t => t.Notes )
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Id);
```

Comment: Would this be implemented on the Note or on the Client and Supplier?

Comment: Client and Supplier, all class with lists of entities

Comment: No, only `Client`. This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Why only Client? Supplier needs the same, relationship

this.HasOptional(t => t.Supplier )
                .WithMany(t => t.Notes )
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Id);

Comment: You can't have one FK pointing to multiple tables (`d.Id` should actually be `d.EntityId`).